# Is there a way to modify the UI in Overwatch?

Tags: overwatch

I know in some other games like Dirty Bomb and TF2 users can tweak the UI through specific config files, and can make their own config files to tweak the UI as they see fit.

I am not seeing an option in the Options menu to reconfigure my UI.  Is there a way to reconfigure the way elements are presented onscreen and adjust the UI at all? I'd like to perhaps move the healthbar and the abilities cooldown closer to the middle to reduce screen clutter around the edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presently there are some options that are configurable in the Options menu (such as turning the kill feed on or off), but many of the UI components are not yet customizable. Blizzard is working on some crosshair customization in the near future.

Source: Reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4ccvgc/crosshair_customization_is_coming_soon which points to a battle.net forum post from about a month ago that is no longer available

Blizzard has also indicated that they would like the spectator experience to match the casual player's UI as much as possible, which will limit the complexity of the customizations that they will be willing to offer.

ETA: There is a hotkey to turn off all UI elements (defaults to Alt-Z). I'm guessing this is for machinima creation purposes and probably not what you are looking for as far as customization.